# Git Deploy to Azure & Assets upload to Azure CDN

Tags: git, azure, deployment, cdn, kudu

I have a website on Azure (App service it's called now), and I have continuous deployment enabled using git deploy from Bitbucket. I would like to serve the assets from Azure CDN, but I don't want that to be a manual process. From all the research that I've done the better option that I found is by using: Post Deployment Action Hooks from Kudu (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks). Not sure if there's a better recommended way or any other documented way available? Thanks!